# XML not displaying to ListView gives error and crashes

Tags: java, android, android-listview, logcat

I am receiving an XML document as variable `xml`, In the debugger i can confirm the XML is grabbed and saved to `data` Properly. Now it never displays in my List the crashes with an error.

My Code:

```
if (xml != null) {
                {
                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                        map.put(KEY_CONTACTTITLE, getValue(e, KEY_CONTACTTITLE));
                        map.put(KEY_NAME, getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                        map.put(KEY_MAINPHONE, getValue(e, KEY_MAINPHONE));
                        map.put(KEY_CELLPHONE, getValue(e, KEY_CELLPHONE));
                        map.put(KEY_FAX, getValue(e, KEY_FAX));
                        map.put(KEY_EMAIL, getValue(e, KEY_EMAIL));
                        menuItems.add(map);
                    }

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, menuItems,
                            R.layout.activity_move_contacts, new String[] {
                                    KEY_CONTACTTITLE, KEY_NAME, KEY_MAINPHONE, KEY_CELLPHONE, KEY_FAX, KEY_EMAIL },
                            new int[] { R.id.ContactTitle, R.id.Name,
                                    R.id.MainPhone, R.id.CellPhone, R.id.Fax, R.id.Email });
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
```

LogCat Error:

```
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.<init>(SimpleAdapter.java:85)
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at com.testingapp.MoveContactsActivity$contentCall.onPostExecute(MoveContactsActivity.java:120)
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at com.testingapp.MoveContactsActivity$contentCall.onPostExecute(MoveContactsActivity.java:1)
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-22 21:31:59.466: E/AndroidRuntime(4482):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I personally have not used adapters too much and believe it quit possible for me to have messed something up.

Comment: What is at line 120? Something is null

Comment: Most likely, `context` is null when you call `new SimpleAdapter(context, ...)`

Comment: @Joe : Seems your right, it was comeing back as null. When i change it to Context context; it gives me this error: The local variable context may not have been initialized How should i call it there?

Comment: Did you figure this out yet? It looks like you are using an AsyncTask inside your Activity. Simply use `MainActivity.this` (assuming your Activity is named `MainActivity) or pass a valid Context to your AsyncTask's constructor.

Comment: @Sam thanks, i was going about it like this : this.MainActivity.